# Ruby style: Default value from a hash

Tags: ruby

Given that I have a hash of opts with possibly missing keys, what is considered better or more idiomatic Ruby? This:

```
my_val = opts.delete(:key){|k| default_value_for_key }
```

or:

```
my_val = opts.delete(:key) || default_value_for_key
```

given that I want to remove the keys from the hash when extracting the values.

Comment: The second sample is nicely readable.

Comment: That's been my default method for doing such a thing for a while, but I recently came across some code that did it the first way, so it got me wondering.

Comment: Note that these two pieces of code don’t always do the same thing. Consider the case when the value is `nil`.

Comment: Well, it works but #2 works and has less visual noise.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall makes a good point. It's important to have a good idea what sort of payload you're going to get. If you don't know, you'll have to be more defensive about your coding, in which case #1 is safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Keyword arguments:**

If you are using Ruby 2.0 or later, the most idiomatic way to do things is to use [keyword arguments](http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/10/08/keyword-arguments-ruby-2-0/):

```
def foo(bar: 10)
  # do something with bar
end
```

The keyword arguments feature automatically takes care of assigning default values and throwing an exception when an unknown key is supplied.

If you are not using Ruby 2.0, or keyword arguments do not work for some other reason, you should decide if your method will detect unknown keys and throw an error, or just silently ignore them.

**Silently ignoring unknown keys:**

```
def foo(opts={})
  bar = opts.fetch(:bar, 10)
  # do something with bar
end
```

Using `fetch` can be better than using `opts[:bar] || 10` because it allows the caller of the method to specify `bar=nil` or `bar=false`.  The `||` operator would result in you overriding any value returned from the hash if it is nil or false.

**Complaining about unknown keys:**

If you have a lot of keys and want to throw an exception when an unknown one is given, you probably should use `delete`.  The idea here is that when you are done deleting known keys, only the unknown ones are left.

```
def foo(opts={})
  opts = opts.dup   # Avoid deleting from the hash the caller passed
                    # in because that would surprise the caller!

  bar = opts.delete(:bar) { 10 }
  # get other options

  raise "Unknown keys #{opts.keys.inspect}" if !opts.empty?

  # do stuff
end
```

Comment: The last example was exactly what I was thinking of doing. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use [`fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) with a default option.

```
my_val = opts.fetch(:key, "default_value_for_key")
```

**EDIT:**

Given that you want to delete the key, the block form is IMHO the way to go since it will return whatever the block evaluates to.

However, the second option is easier on the eyes.

Comment: Yeah, I like that. Sorry I wasn't clear though about deleting the keys out of the hash. Updated my question.